# Listening with socket from async method Python

Tags: python, sockets, async-await

I want my script to do two things:

1. Start some function with infinite loop  and
2. Listen some port using socket.

I tried to run them both as async methods like in sample code below, but foo() is blocked after listen() was started.

```
async def foo(name):
    while True:
        print(name, datetime.datetime.now())
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return await True

async def listen(port):
    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversocket.bind(('localhost', port))
    serversocket.listen(1)

    while True:
        connection, address = serversocket.accept()
        buf = connection.recv(512)
        if len(buf) > 0:
            print(buf)
            break
    return True

async def go_foo(name='foo'):
    b = await foo(name)

async def go_server(port=8089):
    print('server on port', port)
    b = await listen(port)

asyncio.ensure_future(go_server())
asyncio.ensure_future(go_foo())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_forever()
```

How to realize such task correctly?

Comment: The first section in asyncio docs says: _"Asynchronous programming is more complex than classical “sequential” programming: see the Develop with asyncio page which lists common traps and explains how to avoid them. Enable the debug mode during development to detect common issues."_

Comment: ivan, totally useless comment (

Comment: Did you get the debug mode part?